# Specify a domain when using date coordinates?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using `date coordinates in=x` and I would like to use a `soft clip`, which requires a domain. But something like

`domain=2015-07-20 05:00 : 2015-07-20 23:59`

or

`domain={2015-07-20 05:00 : 2015-07-20 23:59}`

does not work. Any idea?

Comment: It could be a syntax problem.  Try putting braces around each date.  Better yet, produce a MWE so we can test solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint given by John in the comment to my question nailed it. The date specifications are to be put into braces separately: `domain={2015-07-20 05:00}:{2015-07-20 23:59}`!